# Automating mac desktop application using selenium and AppiumForMac

Tags: python, macos, selenium, xpath

I am automating a mac desktop application using selenium and AppiumForMac using language Python. I want to locate a set of elements which has same xpath. For this, I have used "find_elements_by_xpath()". But when running the script, I got the following error:

```
File "xxxxx_automation.py", line 740, in <module>
    createNewTemplate()
  File "xxxxx_automation.py", line 102, in createNewTemplate
    roles_supported = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/AXApplication[@AXTitle='XXXXX']/AXWindow[@AXIdentifier='_NS:10' and @AXSubrole='AXStandardWindow']/AXSheet[0]/AXScrollArea[@AXIdentifier='_NS:220']/AXTable[@AXIdentifier='_NS:224']/AXRow[@AXSubrole='AXTableRow']/AXCell[0]/AXButton[@AXIdentifier='RoleCheckBoxButton']")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 366, in find_elements_by_xpath
    return self.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 858, in find_elements
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 297, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/selenium-3.5.0-py2.7.egg/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 194, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

Code snippet that causes error:

```
roles_supported = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/AXApplication[@AXTitle='XXXXX']/AXWindow[@AXIdentifier='_NS:10' and @AXSubrole='AXStandardWindow']/AXSheet[0]/AXScrollArea[@AXIdentifier='_NS:220']/AXTable[@AXIdentifier='_NS:224']/AXRow[@AXSubrole='AXTableRow']/AXCell[0]/AXButton[@AXIdentifier='RoleCheckBoxButton']")
    for roleSupported in roles_supported:
        print "TEST"
        role_name=roleSupported.text
        print role_name
        if role_name == "RtpToMp4-QS":
            clickElement(roleSupported)
            break
            time.sleep(2)
```

Can anybody help in this?

Comment: The error is pretty clear `NoSuchElementException: Message: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.`. That means the `xpath` is not identifying any `WebElement`. Can you update the question with relevant `HTML`?

Comment: When I use driver.find_element_by_xpath(), I can locate the element. But I have to find all the elements with this xpath. So I used driver.find_elements_by_xpath(). But it shows error.

Comment: @DebanjanB This is a desktop application.